# Pass method as a parameter and have it subscribe to an event inside the function?

Tags: c#

I am Class B, and I want to subscribe to an event within A using my method Foo(). However, I would like A to manage the subscription. My thought was to send my method to A and have A subscribe it there, but I am unable to find a pattern of how to do this online. Is what I want even possible?

Please note I am aware in my example below I could subscribe to A's events directly using:

```
this._A.MyEvent += (s, e) => this.MyFunction();
```

but this is not what I am wanting to do. Please don't offer this suggestion as I am aware this is possible.

(Envisioned pattern.)

```
public class A
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void SubscribeToEvent(Func function)
    {
        this.MyEvent += (s, e) => function;
    }

    public void UnsubscribeToEvent(Func function)
    {
        this.MyEvent -= (s, e) => function;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public A _A;

    public B()
    {
        this._A = new A();
    }

    public void MyFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do things
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        this._A.SubscribeToEvent(this.MyFunction);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        this._A.UnsubscribeEvent(this.MyFunction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a change of your method signatures in class `A` your proposed pattern will work.

```
public class A
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void SubscribeToEvent(EventHandler function)
    {
        this.MyEvent += function;
    }

    public void UnsubscribeToEvent(EventHandler function)
    {
        this.MyEvent -= function;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to accomplish this if the signature of the actual function changes? For example, public bool MyFunction(int parameter) { // ... } ?

Comment: Not sure I follow you/what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm not sure to how to articulate my question more clearly - I think it's because I'm struggling to understand the C# event pattern in general, which is probably why my questions are confusing. I appreciate the help though.